# User backend interface in Joomla?

Tags: html, joomla

I am wondering if there is any user back-end manager in Joomla.

I have developed a website and the homepage need to be updated time to time. What my client want is to update it by himself. But I have used a little more HTML tags and he doesn't know about HTML. So is there by chance a non professional user interface so that he can update homepage without knowing the HTML. Or any alternative if possible.

Comment: This question is off topic, but your client should be able to login to the frontend (/?option=com_users) and click the edit icon to edit an article.

Comment: can you please link me to the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Your client can use the Joomla back-end, depending on the version here is some tutorials :

[Joomla 2.5](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2012/item/677-joomla-2-5-beginner-s-guide)

[Joomla 3](http://www.packtpub.com/joomla-3-beginners-guide/book)